# Como obtener la columna con el valor más alto eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, sql, eloquent

Tengo dos tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A partir de las relaciones quiero hacer un **Scope** que muestre la mejor promoción de un servicio.

Este es mi modelo para servicios;

```
<?php
namespace App\Models\Page;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Service extends Model
{
 
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'price'
    ];

    public function promotions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Promotion::class);
    }
}
```

Y este es mi modelo de promociones

```
<?php
namespace App\Models\Page;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Promotion extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'service_id', 'discount','active'
    ];

    public function service(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Service::class);
    }

    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('active', 1);
    }

    public function scopeBestPromotion($query)
    {
        return $query->where('discount',  $query->max('discount'));
    }
}
```

La consulta que estoy haciendo es la siguiente

```
Service::find(1)->active()->bestPromotion()->first();
```

Pero el resultado que tengo no es el que espero:

```
{
   "id":2,
   "service_id":1,
   "discount":"20"
}
```

cuando debería de obtener

```
{
   "id":1,
   "service_id":1,
   "discount":"35"
}
```

Comment: Si los productos tienen varios descuentos. Lo que necesito con el scope es sacar la mayor promoción.

Comment: Encontré el error. El campo lo estaba declarado como varchar por lo que tenia que hacer un max(cast(discount as UNSIGNED)) o corregir el tipo de campo a int o un float

Comment: Deberías publicar tu solución así los demás nos enteramos cual era el error y como lo solucionaste

Comment: La utilidad esta en que los   ```Service``` siempre se van a mostrar o a listar. Sin embargo las ```Promotion``` tiene caducidad. Por otro lado lo engorroso de este sistema es que un  ```Service``` puede tener diferentes ```Promotion``` según la campaña por la que se difunda.